# vImage has same performance as normal loop with dispatch_apply

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, computer-vision, accelerate-framework

This code is run 9600 times inside nested loops for each go, and it has to run in a total time  of under 30ms on an iPhone4S:

```
vImage_Buffer source = { sourceArea.data, patchSide, patchSide, patchSide };
vImage_Buffer destination = { (uchar*)malloc(patchSide * patchSide * sizeof(uchar)), patchSide, patchSide, patchSide };
vImage_AffineTransform transform = { warpingMatrix(0,0), warpingMatrix(0,1), warpingMatrix(1,0), warpingMatrix(1,1), 0, 0 };

if (vImageAffineWarp_Planar8(&source, &destination, NULL, &transform, 0, kvImageBackgroundColorFill) != kvImageNoError)
{
    NSLog(@"Error in warping!");
}
```

It doesn't seem as fast, as it takes about 0.0002 seconds for a 10x10 patch. Am I overlooking some big performance mistake?

The problem I want to solve is matching of backward warped images and this is the first step. The patch is warped 64 times in 64 different positions around a point, for each of max 150 points.

Comment: Move the allocations out of the loop and rerun your test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10x10 is a very small image.  You easily could be spending most of your time in overhead / malloc. Instruments time trace should help determine where the time is going.

The vector ALU on 4s is also half the width of a 5 or 5s, so doesn't provide as much of a win over scalar.

Comment: Instruments says that call to `vImageAffineWarp_Planar8` takes 98% of the time of the method. Do you have any alternative solution?

Comment: vImageAffineWarp_Planar8 doesn't touch any pixels itself.  This work is done by vImageHorizontal/VerticalShear_Planar8. If the samples really are landing in vImageAffineWarp_Planar8 per se, then you are stuck in overhead.   98% of the time spent doing overhead seems much too large and is probably bug worthy if you have a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

vimage is faster if it can reuse the buffers. So if possible declare and allocate the buffer (or the associated data) outside the loop.

```
unsigned char *sourceData = (unsigned char*)malloc(patchSide * patchSide * sizeof(uchar));
vImage_Buffer source = {sourceData, patchSide, patchSide, patchSide};

unsigned char *destinationData = (unsigned char*)malloc(patchSide * patchSide * sizeof(uchar));
vImage_Buffer destination = {destinationData, patchSide, patchSide, patchSide};

loop{
   //fill sourceData e.g. through memcpy
   memcpy(sourceData, somedata, patchSide * patchSide * sizeof(uchar));

   if (vImageAffineWarp_Planar8(&source, &destination, NULL, &transform, 0, kvImageBackgroundColorFill) != kvImageNoError)
   {
     NSLog(@"Error in warping!");
   }
   //destinationData contains the result
}
```

Comment: Copying the source around seems unnecessary. vImage should be able to use it in place.

Comment: That why I wrote e.g. If it can be used it in place so much the better. The point is to allocate the buffer before hand, not in the call as in the 'destination buffer'. I will improve the speed, both according to the documentation and in my experience.

Comment: But I agree on your comment on 10x10 being too small to really see the benefits of vector calculations

Comment: @Sten your example needs to be cleaned up and clearer, but the principle is correct, allocate your vImage_Buffer once. However, probably best to allocate during the object initialization. No need for the memcpy.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two changes you can make to improve performance without much change to your code: using the vImage framework to assign your source/destination buffers and creating a temp buffer for reuse within the loop. A third change might be to change your tile size (see end of this answer).

Documentation for vImage/Accelerate Framework recommends using `vImageBuffer_Init` (see `vImage_Utilities.h`) to initialize your buffers to ensure that the actual buffer is

> sized and aligned for best performance

rather than allocating memory yourself:

```
vImage_Buffer buffer;
vImage_Error err = vImageBuffer_Init(&buffer, height, width, 8 * sizeof(pixel), kvImageNoFlags);
```

where `pixel` in your case will be `Pixel_8` since you are using the `*_Planar8` functions. Note that you will still need to free `buffer.data` when you are done with it.

So you should initialize source and destination outside of your loop:

```
vImage_Buffer source;
vImage_Buffer destination;
vImage_Error err = vImageBuffer_Init(&source, patchSide, patchSide, 8 * sizeof(Pixel_8), kvImageNoFlags);
err = vImageBuffer_Init(&destination, patchSide, patchSide, 8 * sizeof(Pixel_8), kvImageNoFlags);
```

and copy your data from `sourceArea.data` to `source.data`. Keep in mind that `source.rowBytes` is not likely to equal `source.width`.

You should also create a temp buffer so that `vImageAffineWarp_Planar8` can reuse it every iteration instead of allocating it for every iteration since you have passed in `NULL` as the third argument. To determine the dimensions of the temp buffer, you call the function exactly as you will during operation but with the flag `kvImageGetTempBufferSize` since different parameters/flags can require different buffer sizes (see `@constant kvImageGetTempBufferSize` in `vImage_Types.h`):

```
size_t tempBufferSize = vImageAffineWarp_Planar8(&source, &destination, NULL, &transform, 0, kvImageBackgroundColorFill | kvImageGetTempBufferSize);
```

You would then allocate the temp buffer:

```
void *tempBuffer = malloc(tempBufferSize);
```

And finally in your loop you would use `tempBuf` every time:

```
if (vImageAffineWarp_Planar8(&source, &destination, &tempBuffer, &transform, 0, kvImageBackgroundColorFill) != kvImageNoError)
{
    NSLog(@"Error in warping!");
}
```

So to re-cap, source, destination, and `tempBuf` are all pre-allocated using `vImageBuffer_Init` prior to the loop, where the required size of tempBuf is determined by calling `vImageAffineWarp_Planar8` as you will in your loop, but with the additional flag `kvImageGetTempBufferSize`. Hopefully that will speed you up a little!

One final thing you might look at if your algorithm supports it would be working on larger tiles or image stripes (see section `Tiling / Strip Mining and Multithreading` in `vImage.h`).